# File upload: Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, debugging, backbone.js

I had an element `<input type="file" name="name" id="name" value="<%= name %>" >` and I got the error `Uncaught Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11`. I read that adding a value to an input element of type 'file' can cause this error so I removed the value attribute but I get the same error. I haven't done anything but add this element to my form so the other solutions I saw didn't seem relevant to me. What could cause uploading a file using that element to give this error?

If it matters, this is in a backbone template file with extension .jst.ejs

If you don't know why, maybe you can help with debugging? What I'm doing now is using Chrome dev tools to step through the jQuery and Javascript files and this isn't really helping. Are there more efficient ways to debug this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't also have some javascript somewhere trying to set the value attribute of this input? Just having the `value=` attribute in the HTML tag shouldn't trigger this exception, only trying to set it via javascript should.

Comment: It's happening in the backbone_datalink.js file but I don't know how to change this because it attaches a change event to all input elements in the form.